# MsgBox(mail.To) email address only and not friendly name

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

Is there a way I can use the following command MsgBox(mail.To) within a onitemsend using to return the email address only, and the friendly/alias name?  I need the email address alone as its used for a SQL lookup against our CRM.  At the moment if I use MsgBox(mail.To) i get:

Joe Bloggs (joe.bloggs@company.com) 
but I'd like:
joe.bloggs@company.com

I believe it does this because Outlook looks up the email in my address book because there is an entry which cant be helped.

Many Thanks

Comment: Of what type is your mail object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim str As String = mail.To
    Dim lst As String() = str.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim email As String = ""
    For Each w1 In lst
        If w1.Contains("@") Then
            email = w1
        End If
    Next
    email = email.Replace("(", "")
    email = email.Replace(")", "")
    MsgBox(email)
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to do that if there is the MailItem.Recipients collection with the Recipient object explicitly exposing Name and Address properties.

Comment: I didn't know that `MailItem.Recipients` existed. Thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and loop through all recipients. Use the `Recipient.Address` / `Name` / `Type` properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail = New MailMessage()
mail.From = New MailAddress("your@mail.com", "Your Firends Name")
```

maybe?